# JsxGraph from Dart using Dart JS interop

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop, jsxgraph

I am trying to use the plotting library [JSXGraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/) from Dart using dart js but I have problems.

This is working javascript code

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard(
    'box',
    {
      boundingbox: [-10, 10, 2, -1],
      axis: true,
      keepaspectratio: false,
      showNavigation: false
    }
);
var graph = board.create(
    'functiongraph',
    [function(x){ return 3*x*x + 5*x + 1;}, -10, 10],
    {strokeColor: '#ffff00'}
);
```

You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wr0vga8L/4/) on jsFiddle.

I want to do basically the identicall thing but from dart. This is what I have come up with so far:

```dart
JsObject jsxGraph = context['JXG']['JSXGraph'];
var board = jsxGraph.callMethod('initBoard', [
  'box',
  new JsObject.jsify({
    'boundingbox': [-10, 10, 2, -1],
    'axis': true,
    'keepaspectratio': false,
    'showNavigation': false
  })
]);
var graph = board.callMethod('create', [
  'functiongraph',
  [(x){return 3*x*x + 5*x + 1;}, -10, 10],
  new JsObject.jsify({'strokeColor': '#ffff00'})
]);
```

I get the plot area and axes but I can't get the actual plot line. Instead, there is an error on the console: `Uncaught TypeError: this.Y is not a function`.

Could someone, please, point me to what I could be doing wrong? I suspect it is something about the callback function but I really don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `jsify` missing in your code:

```dart
JsObject jsxGraph = context['JXG']['JSXGraph'];
var board = jsxGraph.callMethod('initBoard', [
  'box',
  new JsObject.jsify({
    'boundingbox': [-10, 10, 2, -1],
    'axis': true,
    'keepaspectratio': false,
    'showNavigation': false
  })
]);
var graph = board.callMethod('create', [
  'functiongraph',
  new JsObject.jsify([(x){return 3*x*x + 5*x + 1;}, -10, 10]},
  new JsObject.jsify({'strokeColor': '#ffff00'})
]);
```

Comment: Thanks! It was not the only thing though. I almost banged my head against the keyboard. For some reason, in dart, the callback function must take two arguments of which the first one actually held the ``x`` value and the other one was a boolean with meaning I'm not aware of, even the documentation of JSXGraph does not talk about second parameter.